# Default load of all data then filter table with form

Tags: php, html, forms, mysqli

I have a page that loads invoices for clients. I added a date picker to search by date but when the page loads it gives no data until a filter is applied from a form. I want the page to load with all data first then if user wants to filter by date, they can select that.

```
 <form method='post' action='invoices.php' class='sdate'>



    <div class="sdate">

      <input type="text" name="sdate" placeholder="Start Date" >
    </div>


        <div class="sdate">
      <button type="submit" class="sdatebtn">Submit</button>
    </div>


    </form>
```

database query

```
                FROM imw_locations l
                INNER JOIN vzw_invoice i
                ON l.AddressCode=i.ItemCustomerFullName
                WHERE l.owner='" . $owner . " ' AND Txndate='".$sdate."'
```

Full Data of query

```
<head>


</head>

<?php

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    header('Location: /index.php');
    exit();
}



?>
<?php 

include "config.php";
$owner = $_SESSION['role'];


$sdate = $_POST['sdate'];
$edate = $_POST['edate'];


?>
<?php include "../../assets/navbar.php" ?>
<div>
<?php echo $sdate;?>
<!----    Date Selections    ---->
 <form method='post' action='invoices.php' class='sdate'>



    <div class="sdate">

    <input type="text" name="sdate" placeholder="Start Date">
    </div>
    <div class="sdate">

    <input type="text" name="edate" placeholder="End Date" >
    </div>


        <div class="sdate">
      <button type="submit" class="sdatebtn">Submit</button>
    </div>


    </form>







<!---- This is the download form ---->
 <form method='post' action='../finance/export/download.php'>
  <input type='submit' value='Export' name='Export'>

  <table class="invoice">
  <thead>
    <tr>

<th>Reference Number</th>
<th>Memo</th>
<th>Trans. Date</th>
<th>Location</th>
<th>Item Amount</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Vendor</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
<?php 

     $owner = $_SESSION['role'];
     $query = "SELECT l.AddressCode, 
                l.owner,
                l.City, 
                l.State, 
                l.Zip, 
                i.RefNumber,
                i.memo,
                i.Txndate,
                i.DueDate,
                i.ItemCustomerFullName,
                i.PO_number ,
                i.ItemAmount, 
                i.PO_number,
                i.preorder_,
                i.Quantity,
                i.Vendor,
                i.balance
                FROM imw_locations l
                INNER JOIN vzw_invoice i
                ON l.AddressCode=i.ItemCustomerFullName
                WHERE l.owner='" . $owner . " ' 
                AND Txndate='".$sdate."'


                ";
     $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
     $user_arr = array();
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      $ref = $row['RefNumber'];
      $memo = $row['memo'];
      $Txndate = $row['Txndate'];
      $duedate = $row['DueDate'];
      $ItemCustomerFullName = $row['City'];
      $PO_number = $row['PO_number'];
      $ItemAmount = $row['ItemAmount'];
      $preorder_ = $row['preorder_'];
      $Quantity = $row['Quantity'];
      $Vendor = $row['Vendor'];
      $balance = $row['balance'];

   ?>
      <tr>

       <td><?php echo $ref; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $memo; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $Txndate; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $ItemCustomerFullName; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $ItemAmount; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $Quantity; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $Vendor; ?></td>


      </tr>
   <?php
    }
   ?>
   </table>
   <?php 
    $serialize_user_arr = serialize($user_arr);
   ?>
  <textarea name='export_data' style='display: none;'><?php echo $serialize_user_arr; ?></textarea>
 </form>


</div>
```

Comment: Could you show the code that queries the database? Basically, you need to see if date is set, and then include it in the `WHERE` clause of the DB query. What is probably happening is that you query where date is NULL, which returns empty

Comment: @Ice76 I have updated my post with the query

Comment: a sidenote. `array($ref,$memo,$Txndate,$duedate,$ItemCustomerFullName,$PO_number,$ItemAmount,$preorder_,$Quantity,$Vendor,$balance);` is essentially equal to `$row`. You can get rid of a good screenful of useless code

Comment: @YourCommonSense haha yes thank you.  I actually had that in from a previous script and neglected to remove it.  Thank you

Comment: Also the BETWEEN does not work for me.  Should I ask in separate thread?

Comment: between is likely not working because $_POST['edate'] doesn't seem to have a counterpart form field.  I am also puzzled why echo $email; in the sdate field. The code looks like a Frankenstein build of several random code parts. is it?

Comment: I got the BETWEEN working with this: pastebin.com/HFvd6w7Q  @YourCommonSense its not really frankensteined lol.  I have a few things I have done on my server that I am using similar script.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 2):

This is tough to answer as the code you posted does not line up with the query you mentioned above it.

The simplest solution would be to set a variable with a string, and append to it if the date is set. This is a simple solution, as you get more conditions, you can make an array and then do an `implode` on it, but that could be added later. An example:

```
$whereClause = "WHERE l.owner = '{$owner}'";
if ( ! empty( $sdate) && $sdate ) {
    $whereClause .= " AND Txndate = '{$sdate}'";
}
```

As far as your `BETWEEN` clause, try switching the dates. I am assuming that `$edate` is end date and `$sdate` is start date, and the between clause takes starting date first.

Also, PLEASE read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/5749295). You have clear examples of security holes, big ones. You are taking user input and directly injecting it into the DB query. That is a HUGE security hole, and the input needs to be verified and cleaned.

Comment: Would you accept a challenge of writing a secure version?

Comment: I have updated my OP to include all of invoice.php file.   Hope this helps.  I tried the above but that did not work for me.  This gave me a blank page.

Comment: @DavidMorin you have to realize that an answer is not supposed to be a deliberately working example that you just mindlessly copy and paste into your code. You are rather supposed to *understand* the way it works and *implement* in your environment.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I would!

Comment: @DavidMorin Please check for error and why the blank page happened. You could also tell me how you implemented my code and I can look, but you should first understand why you got a blank page

Comment: @YourCommonSense Your absolutely correct.  In what way would I implement the above code into my example.  I am not understanding how to place this.

Comment: @DavidMorin Hey, take a look at this. I adjusted it to comply with your between clause, but what it does is determine what the `WHERE` should be, then just paste it into the query. https://pastebin.com/NxznBuEL

Comment: @Ice76 Close to mine but yours is much cleaner.  Thank you sir for that.